# Reading from numbers and letters from a file

Tags: c++, c++11

i have a little problem. I try to read some numbers and letters from a file into my programm. The file looks always like this:

```
15 12 7
8 5 A
12 7 B
4 9 C
```

etc.

I'd like to save the data starting from the second row in an array, ie: array[8][5] = A

So now i got this example code about how i can read from files:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if(argc < 2) {
    cout << "Please insert file-name" << endl;
    return 1;
    }

    ifstream input(argv[1]);
    int i(0), temp;

    while(input >> temp) {
    cout << ++i << ". Number: " << temp << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My problem now is that if i use (my idea was to put them first into one array and sort them later into 2d array):

```
while(input >> tmp)
```

it stops at the first letter, since tmp is from type int. But if i use char instead, it saves every character, so out of 12 i get 1 and 2 ...

While using (to get them direct into my 2d array):

```
while(input >> a >> b >> c)
```

(while c is from type char) doesnt get me any output.
I feel like the solution isnt very hard, but somehow i'm not getting the solution. I'd be very happy if someone could help me out! Ty

Comment: You need to keep track of which line you are on, as sometimes the third element is a letter and sometimes a number.

Comment: @vienya Is array of `std::string` a possible solution? Or do you need to perform some calculations? Well, you can always make `std::vector<int>` out of this array.

Comment: @LogicStuff unfortunately i didnt learned this yet :/

Comment: I mixed up, forget about it.

Comment: Well if only the first line has all numbers, you can use a counter and check if it is 0 or not. It depends on the layout of your file.

Comment: @NeilKirk yeah its only the first line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works for me

```
int x, y;
char c;
std::ifstream input("file.txt");
while (input >> x >> y >> c)
{
    std::cout << x << " " << y << " " << c << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but only until after the first character. So my output would be like this: 15 12 7 8 5 A ... how can i continue it?

Comment: @vienya as long as the input is in correct format, it should work.

Comment: well that's weird. meantime i got a pretty bad workaround with getline and splitting the string, i'm gonna ask my tutor then soon, but ty for ur help

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work, however, I'm not sure if it'll handle invalid input correctly:

```
while(input)
{
    if(input >> temp) // was extraction to temp successful?
        cout << ++i << ". Number: " << temp << endl;
    else // otherwise
    {
        input.ignore(); // extract one character
        input.clear(); // clear error flags
    }
}
```

Comment: it's not doing anything :/